# Transaction Controller is Not Showing Overall response time of all Samples

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have multiple samples under Transaction Controller but in aggregate report it is showing individual samples instead of showing overall response time of transaction controller.
In my Script for Transaction Controller i have already checked in Generate Parent Sample
and also I have updated the meter.properties file to

```
summariser.ignore_transaction_controller_sample_result=false
```

but still seeing same issue
I am using Jmeter5.0 ,does anyone know why it is not showing results on Transaction controller level
It is only happening when I am running test in non-gui modern GUI mode it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default functionality since JMeter 5.0 introduced in ticket [62470](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62470).

There is a possibility to revert JMeter to previous behaviour, you will need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [JMeter Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 1):

**Uncheck "Save Sub Results"** as part of the Aggregate Report Listener configuration and then re-run the test.

[image]

This should provide the CSV without individual sampler results.

Additionally, even in GUI mode, if this option is not unchecked, the CSV being created will have individual sample results. However, the Aggregate Report UI will show only Transaction level details.

This supposed issue is seen in JMeter 5.0 since "Save Sub Results" option is now available in CSV as well unlike previous versions which had only the option in XML.