# [JMeter]_Incorrect summary report got generated when we run the script from the command line

Tags: jmeter, summary

I have some web services to test on Jmeter. Added a Summary Report listener using JMeter in NON-GUI mode. Here is the file I am getting after configuring the summary report through JMeter.
Note: Have multiple if controllers, each if controller has Transaction controller, could you please find below digram

**Threadgroup** 
Transaction controller 1
Transaction controller 2
If controller 1
-- > Transaction controller 3
If controller 2
--- > Transaction controller 4
If controller 3
--- > Transaction controller 5
If controller 4
-- > Transaction controller 6
If controller 5
--- > Transaction controller 7
If controller 6
--- > Transaction controller 8

Here you can see "Navigate to URL" is written 4 times, that means thread count was 4.

I want to group these 4 entries just like in the actual summary report and all the other values should be average of this.
similarly I want to group of below samplers

/ubo/Reference/mapinfo/DE
/ubo/Reference/entityinfo/US
Login 
---
etc
[Summary Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfHG9.png)

[Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0GIW.png)

Comment: @okesh Try this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234099/transaction-controller-is-not-showing-overall-response-time-of-all-samples), It might help your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking into [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) which has one entry per sample result with timestamp, response time, response message, etc.

If you're looking for the [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener textual representation you either need to:

- Open the .jtl file in JMeter GUI using Summary Report (or other listener of your choice) by using "Browse" button:

  [image]

  and the Listener with interpret/group sample results, calculate average response times, etc. the output can be stored using "Save Table Data" button
- The same can be achieved using [JMeter Plugins Command Line tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line), if you install it and [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) you will be able to generate the table out of the .jtl results file using the following command:

  ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv SummaryReport.csv --input-jtl /your/test/results.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport
  ```